# Displaying Image From SQlite in listView Lags

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, imageview, lag

I'm Displaying images and Some text in list view when user capture his image i store it in db as blob and display it in listview but it lagging too much sometime it crashes.

here is my DbUtitlity Class to convert image in byte[] and bitmap

```
public class DbBitmapUtility{
       public static byte[] getImageBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }

    public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image,0,image.length);
    }

    public static byte[] getBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        int len = 0;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    }


}
```

And This is my CustomerAdapter class

```
class CustomerAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Bitmap bitmap=null;

CustomerAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, parent, false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.txtFname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtFname);
    holder.txtLname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtLname);
    holder.txtPaid = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtPaidBill);
    holder.txtUnPaid = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtUnpaid);
    holder.txtTotalUnPaid = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTotalUnpaid);
    holder.txtCustomerID = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtCustomerID);
    holder.txtMobileNo = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtMobileNo);
    holder.imageView = (CircleImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_pic);
    v.setTag(holder);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    //getting image byte[] from db
    byte[] img = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(Customer.USERAVATAR));
    if(img !=null) {
        //getting bitmap from byte[]
        bitmap = DbBitmapUtility.getImage(img);
    }
    if (bitmap != null) {
        //setting image to imageView
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    holder.txtFname.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Customer.FNAME)));
    holder.txtLname.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Customer.LNAME)));
    holder.txtPaid.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Customer.PAID)));
    holder.txtUnPaid.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Customer.UNPAID)));
    holder.txtTotalUnPaid.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Customer.UNPAID))+" ₹");
    holder.txtCustomerID.setText(String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Customer.KEYID))));
    holder.txtMobileNo.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Customer.MOBILENO)));

    //imageView Listener
    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context,UpdateCustomer.class);
            i.putExtra("ID", holder.txtCustomerID.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("FNAME",holder.txtFname.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("MOBILENO", holder.txtMobileNo.getText().toString());
            context.startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtFname;
    TextView txtLname;
    TextView txtPaid;
    TextView txtUnPaid;
    TextView txtTotalUnPaid;
    TextView txtCustomerID;
    TextView txtMobileNo;
    CircleImageView imageView;

  }
}
```

Logcat
`02-23 18:07:16.017 20945-1125/shazdroid.com.raviapp V/FA: Using measurement      service
02-23 18:07:16.022 20945-1125/shazdroid.com.raviapp V/FA: Connecting to remote service
02-23 18:07:16.027 20945-20945/shazdroid.com.raviapp W/ActivityThread: AppLock checkAppLockState isAppLocked = false pkgName = shazdroid.com.raviapp showWhenLocked = false
02-23 18:07:16.052 20945-20945/shazdroid.com.raviapp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@383cc74 time:368732045
02-23 18:07:16.087 20945-1125/shazdroid.com.raviapp V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 1145561340
02-23 18:07:16.097 20945-1125/shazdroid.com.raviapp D/FA: Connected to remote service
02-23 18:07:16.097 20945-1125/shazdroid.com.raviapp V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
02-23 18:07:17.862 20945-20945/shazdroid.com.raviapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
02-23 18:07:17.982 20945-20945/shazdroid.com.raviapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
02-23 18:07:18.782 20945-20945/shazdroid.com.raviapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
02-23 18:07:18.817 20945-20945/shazdroid.com.raviapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
02-23 18:07:19.177 20945-20945/shazdroid.com.raviapp W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 367444 bytes, free space 339159 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
02-23 18:07:19.592 20945-20955/shazdroid.com.raviapp I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1157(61KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(19MB) LOS objects, 20% free, 61MB/77MB, paused 811us total 129.950ms
02-23 18:07:19.822 20945-20945/shazdroid.com.raviapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
02-23 18:07:19.832 20945-20945/shazdroid.com.raviapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
02-23 18:07:20.932 20945-20945/shazdroid.com.raviapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
02-23 18:07:21.047 20945-20945/shazdroid.com.raviapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
02-23 18:07:21.117 20945-1125/shazdroid.com.raviapp V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
02-23 18:07:21.892 20945-20945/shazdroid.com.raviapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
02-23 18:07:22.017 20945-20945/shazdroid.com.raviapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1`

I m new to android please help me i have heared about caching but doesnt know how to implement it.
And Even all the imageView shows same image in whole list if i set image to one customer but later after setting image to all customer it get ok?

Comment: post your logcat here so we can help you

Comment: Use [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or 
[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/) for caching and image loading.

Comment: You should store the path of image not the whole image in db..

Comment: but where should i store the image?

Comment: how can i use caching library for caching images from db?

Comment: best way is store images in file system and store path in database. Or if your images is confidential then you can use blob data type of sqlite. and to display in listview you have to use LruChache

Comment: I'd suggest not storing the physical image as a BLOB in the db, only the path to it - extract that from the db, and pass that to an asynchronous image loading/caching library like Glide.  glide will handle loading the image from only its location from image path.  Your key problem is synchronous image loading.

Comment: can it is possible to store image in assets folder at runtime?

Comment: Store the image in local storage - INTERNAL (app specific location i.e. where db's/preference files are stored - `/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/`) or EXTERNAL (public like images folder)

Comment: @Shaz no it is not possible!

Comment: Shaz You can follow @MarkKeen suggestions for storage of images.

Comment: cant i compress my bitmap so some extent that can improve my performance?

Comment: any compression will have a performance hit - i.e. WORSE performance.

Comment: Thanks for answers guys... ;)